# How To Customize Tesseract Ignores Noise?

Tags: c#, opencv, character, ocr, tesseract

I've a image like this (white background and black text). If there is not noise (as you can see: the top and bottom of number line has many noise), Tesseract can recognize number very good.

But when has noise, Tesseract try to recognize it as number and add more number to result. It is really bad. How can I make Tesseract Ignore Noise? I can't make a preprocessing image to make it more contrast or sharp text. This doesn't help anything.

If some tool can to hightlight only string line. It can be really good input to Tesseract. Please help me. Thanks everybody.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should try [eroding and dilating](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html):

> The most basic morphological operations are two: Erosion and Dilation.
>   They have a wide array of uses, i.e. :
>
> Removing noise
>
> ...

Answer (score 3):

you could try to down sample your binary image and sample it up again (`pyrDown` and `PyrUp`) or you could try to `smooth` your image with an gaussian blur. And, as already suggested, `erode` and `dilate` your image.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 solutions for your problem:

1. As already sugested - try using `erode` and `dilate` or some kind of blur. It's the simplest solution.
2. Find all contours (`findContours` function) and then delete all contours with area less then some value (try different values, you should find correct one quite fast). Note that the value may not be constant - for example you can try to use 80% of average contour area (just add all contours areas, divide it by number of contours and multiply by 0.8).
3. Find all contours. Create one dimension array of integers, with length equal to your image height. Fill array with zeros. Now for each contour:
   I. Find the top and the bottom point (points with the biggest and the smallest value of y coordinate). Let's name this points `T` and `B`.
   II. Add one to all elements of array which index is between `B.y` and `T.y`. (so if B = (1, 4) and T = (3, 11) then add one to array[4], array[5], array[6] ..., array[11]).
   Find the biggest element of array. Let's name this value `v`. All contours for which `B.y <= v <= T.y` should be letters, other contours - noise.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily remove these noises by using image processing techniques(Morphological operations like erode and dilate) you can choose opencv for this operations.

Answer (score 0):

Do connected component labeling....that is blob counting....all dose noises can never match the size of the numbers....with morphological techniques the numbers also get modified...label the image...count the number of pixels in each labeled region and set a threshold (which you can easily set as you will only have numbers and noises)...cvblob is the library written in C++ available at code googles...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem: small noises was cause of tesseract fails. I cannot use open-cv, because I was developing some feature on android, and open-cv was unwanted because of it large size. I don't know if this solution is good, but here is what I did.

I found all black regions in image (points of each region I added to own region set). Then, I check if count of point in this region is bigger than some threshold, like 10, 25 and 50. If true, I make white all points of that region.